# How to send a notification to specific platform?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send two different notifications to Android and iOS. I want to send a notification message to iOS, this way iOS displays a nice notification. For Android I want to send a data message, this way I can handle the notification on Android and also in the background (because I don't get a callback in the background and want to handle it myself).

I looked through the docs, but couldn't find anything about sending to a specific platform. How do I do that?

Also other suggestions on how to do this are welcome, but keep in mind that I specifically want to handle the notification myself through a callback on Android (onMessageReceived)

Comment: I think that you will need to store on the server side info about devices with Os type and firebase device token. Than your application that is reponsible for sending notifications should find iOS and Android devices and send correct notification as you want. I have done it this way, and I can achive similar functionality in my environment

Comment: @PatrykJabłoński That could be done, but then you're not using the power of Firebase. I could also subscribe to the topic Android which would be better, but still not really what I'm looking for. Firebase should have all this information, I just don't know how to use it. For example from the console you can send a message specifically to the Android version of the app. I just cannot find it in the docs through the http api and I also need to send it to a specific topic.

Comment: Do you want to send push notification from one device to another? @KevinvanMierlo

Comment: I agree that it should have such information, but I have never seen in firebase console possibility to send notification to specific OS type. I have onle seen possibility to send it to application, specific device (by token) and topic. If you would find it please share this information with me :)

Comment: @Yuyutsu No. I'm sending the push notifications from the server to the devices. The only problem I'm having is that Android can't handle push notifications when the app is in the background (with notification message). That's why I wanted to send push separately to Android and iOS. So I could use the data message on Android and notification message on iOS

Comment: can you please show me your curl request from server side?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message in here stays nothing about sending notifications to specific platform, so I assume that there is no such possibility and you need to handle it by your own or try with topics (but I have never used topic, so I do not know how to use it).

Comment: @Yuyutsu Well, I'm asking here how I should do the request so I can send a push message to a specific platform and specific topic. Right now I'm only sending to a topic. So it's something like this:   {
    "to" : "topics/topic",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }

Comment: @PatrykJabłoński Yeah that was my fear as well. I just don't understand why I can't handle the notification in the background on Android. That would fix all.

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo can you explain me how you would like to handle notification in background on android? I have an mechanism in my application that is handling notifications in background without displaing anything on device. For example it was starting synchronisation of data on specific "silent" notification on android and it was working well.

Comment: @PatrykJabłoński The problem that I'm having is that if I send a notification message (notification key is in json) that Firebase will handle the push when the app is in the background. When I send a data message (data key is in json) then I can do it myself, which works. The problem there is that iOS doesn't display a notification anymore (iOS needs a notification message). So all I need is handling the notification message in the background or being able to send the push separately to Android and iOS.

Comment: did you get notification from by sending from firebase notification compose? both ios and android

Comment: @Yuyutsu I did, but the notification is generated by Firebase when the app is in the background (on Android) and that's not what I want

Comment: is it work with iOS too @KevinvanMierlo

Comment: @Yuyutsu Yeah, I just told you that. Notification messages works on both platforms, but on Android the notification is generated by Firebase when the app is in the background. Data messages works for Android but not for iOS (it doesn't generate a notification, which makes sense, but is not what I want)

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo First check APNs Certificates. for iOS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153241/discussion-between-yuyutsu-and-kevin-van-mierlo).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**: A recent feature was added for FCM that gives an option to provide specific params for specific platforms, called [Platform Overrides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#customizing_a_message_across_platforms):

> ## Customizing a message across platforms
>
> Messages sent by the FCM v1 HTTP protocol can contain two types of JSON key pairs:
>
> - a common set of keys to be interpreted by all app instances that receive the message.
> - platform-specific blocks of keys interpreted only by app instances running on the specified platform.
>
> Platform-specific blocks give you flexibility to customize messages for different platforms to ensure that they are handled correctly when received. In many scenarios, it makes sense to use both common keys and platform-specific keys in a given message.
>
> ### When to use common keys
>
> - Whenever you're targeting app instances on **all** platforms — iOS, Android, and web
> - When you are sending messages to topics
>
> The common keys that are interpreted by all app instances regardless of platform are `message.notification.title`, `message.notification.body`, and `message.data`.
>
> ### When to use platform-specific keys
>
> - When you want to send fields only to particular platforms
> - To send platform-specific fields in addition to the common keys
>
> Whenever you want to send values to specific platforms only, don't use common keys; use platform-specific key blocks. For example, to send a notification to only iOS and web but not Android, you must use two separate blocks of keys, one for iOS and one for web.
>
> When you are sending messages with specific delivery options, use platform-specific keys to set them. You can specify different values per platform if you want; but even when you want to set essentially the same value across platforms, you must use platform-specific keys. This is because each platform may interpret the value slightly differently — for example, time-to-live is set on Android as an expiration time in seconds, while on iOS it is set as an expiration *date*.
>
> ### Example: notification message with platform-specific delivery options
>
> The following v1 send request sends a common notification title and content to all platforms, but also sends some platform-specific overrides. Specifically, the request:
>
> - sets a long time-to-live for Android and Web platforms, while setting the APNs (iOS) message priority to a low setting
> - sets the appropriate keys to define the result of a user tap on the notification on Android and iOS — `click_action`, and `category`, respectively.

```
{
  "message":{
     "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
     "notification":{
       "title":"Match update",
       "body":"Arsenal goal in added time, score is now 3-0"
     },
     "android":{
       "ttl":"86400s",
       "notification"{
         "click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"
       }
     },
     "apns": {
       "headers": {
         "apns-priority": "5",
       },
       "payload": {
         "aps": {
           "category": "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
         }
       }
     },
     "webpush":{
       "headers":{
         "TTL":"86400"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

> See the [HTTP v1 reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages) for complete detail on the keys available in platform-specific blocks in the message body. For more information about building send requests that contain the message body, see [Build Send Requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message).

---

I remember answering a similar question before but cant seem to find it. There is currently no option to specify which platform a message would be sent. The simplest way you could do this is by using Topics Messaging.

Everytime the token is generated for the first time, you determine from your client app the Platform type and subscribe them to the corresponding topic (e.g. `topics/(Android/iOS)_<Your App Name>`), then sned the messages as needed.

It's also good to keep track of the registration tokens from your Server, if you're using Firebase DB, you could put them inside a node:

```
/pushTokens
  /android
    /{userId} : string
  /ios
    /{userid}: string
```

This would let you check from your backend side and adjust your payload as needed when sending single messages.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad there isn't a nice way to use Firebase in foreground and background on Android and keep iOS the same. But this will probably be the best solution there is for now.

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo See my update. I haven't tried Platform overrides myself, but it seems to be what you were originally looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into that. It definitely looks like the thing I wanted.

Comment: Platform Overrides seems to be the right direction. For example, to send only to iOS devices: don't include the common, top-level, `notifications` key and move those values to the `apns` section, following Apple's `payload` dict structure.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue with Android Development. We used Laravel on backend side.
On backend side, developer has to maintain different scenario for both platforms.

**In Android :**

```
FCM::sendTo($tokens, $option, null, $data);
```

Here, null is passed as a notification builder. When you pass null in notification and create databuilder($data), you can receive message in **onMessageReceived** method when app in background.

**For iOS :**

```
FCM::sendTo($tokens, $option, $notification, $data);
```

Here, you can pass notification builder in $notification. So, iOS device can also get notification.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that the server has to know which device is Android and which device is iOS. There isn't a way to differentiate between iOS and Android with Firebase except the answer provided by AL.

Comment: You must have the information about OS on your server when user login.

Comment: Yeah, but that's a problem because then you can't use the topics or other stuff provided by Firebase anymore. We use this solution in another project because it only has individual push notifications. But this app needs topics.