# Sending to different platforms not working

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase for send notifications in Android and ios, I am getting device id's in array with device type. I have two device type "Android" and "iOS"

Then I am using following condition:

```
if($type == "ios"){
$this->send_ios_notfication($token_number,$message, 'New Message');         
 }else if($type == "Android"){
    $this->send_android_notfication($token_number,$message, 'New Message');
 }
```

But I am getting Notification on One device only. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked in a project and for that we opt in to use `topics`

Android devices I registered in topic `android` and iOS devices are registered in topic `ios`.

So in server side, I send message to `topics/android` and/or `topics/ios`

Source:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_topics

Answer (score 0):

Your `if-else-if` is only doing one block then breaks, hence if it goes through `ios` first, then it would ignore the `android` block after.

From the code you have, it doesn't really look like there's any difference between the `send_ios_notfication` and `send_android_notfication` -- I assume you are changing the payload format there.

FCM v1 has a feature called [Platform Overrides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#customizing_a_message_across_platforms) which you might look into to better work with [multiple platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45973117/4625829).

Comment: Thanks for reply AL but I am using different FCM server access key into both send_ios_notfication and send_android_notfication and both functions are suing curl for send notifiation into respective devices.

Comment: Are the server keys from the same project?

Comment: There is one app we are creating for Android and ios so we have created two projects in FCM

Comment: You could actually just use a single project for both apps and use the same server key for both Android and iOS. It'd be easier.

Comment: OK I will try, Thanks